# Java, problem in Java with a Class in a jar file

Tags: java

My problem is with code that was working before:

```
public CachedRowSetImpl getObjectsRowSet(String selectStatement) {
    selectStatement = selectStatement.replace("false", "0");
    selectStatement = selectStatement.replace("true", "-1");
    selectStatement = selectStatement.replace("FALSE", "0");
    selectStatement = selectStatement.replace("TRUE", "-1");
    CachedRowSetImpl rowSet = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = this.dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(selectStatement);
        rowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        rowSet.populate(result);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        MainFrame.displayExitErrorMessage(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            MainFrame.displayExitErrorMessage(e);
        }
    }
    return rowSet;
}
```

I am getting the message: "CachedRowSetImpl cannot be resolved to a type". I don't know why I lost the jar file, but I was able to down load com.sun.rowset with CachedRowSetImpl.class. I was able to set the jar file at libraries at "Java Build Pat" and everything shows in Package Explorer at Referenced Libraries. I cannot understand what is going wrong?

Comment: It needs to be added to your classpath as well.

Comment: Are you using gradle?  Maven?  Some other build tool? If you're using a build tool, please post its configuration.